# Left join without multiple rows from right table

Tags: sql, sql-server, teradata

I have two tables (`User` and `Salary`). I want to do a `left join` from `User` to `Salary`. For each user I want their name and salary. In case they have no salary that field can be left empty. So far a left join is all we need. But I only want one row per user. Due to some defects there can be several salaries for one user (see table salary). I only want one row per user which can be selected randomly (or top 1). How do I do that? The expected output is presented in the bottom.

User Table:

```
User Name
1    Adam
2    Al
3    Fred
```

Salary Table

```
User  Salary
1     1000
2     2000
2     2000
```

Expected table:

```
User Name  Salary
1    Adam  1000
2    Al    2000 
3    Fred  null
```

Comment: When you have multiple duplicate users in the salary table, are there ever different salaries attached to them?

Comment: And why do you allow duplicate rows for a user in the salaries table???

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Changed `User` to `Userid` as `User` is a reserved word in SQL

```
SELECT u.Userid, u.Name, MAX(S.Salary)
FROM Usertable u
LEFT JOIN Salarytable s ON u.Userid = s.userid
GROUP BY u.userid, u.name
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ce4a8/1/0

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
select U.User, U.Name, min(S.Salary)
from UserTable U
left join SalaryTable S on S.User = U.User
group by U.User, U.Name
```

Comment: Maybe it should be max(S.Salary)

Comment: @PSVSupporter OP's don't care about it :)

Answer (score 3):

Use a derived table to get distinct rows from salaries table.

```
select u.userid, u.username, s.salary
from users u left join (select distinct userid, salary from salaries) s
  on u.userid = s.userid
```

Also, renamed tables and columns. Table names should normally end with s (since pluralis.) Columns should not.

Or, do a `GROUP BY`:

```
select u.userid, u.username, max(s.salary)
from users u left join salaries s
  on u.userid = s.userid
group by u.userid, u.username
```

Or skip the left join, instead do a correlated sub-query:

```
select u.userid, u.username, (select max(s.salary) from salaries s
                              where u.userid = s.userid)
from users
```

Comment: Sorry to comment on an old answer. Do you know which one of those 3 queries would have a smaller performance impact?

Comment: @AJPerez, I don't know SQL Server that well, so it would only be a guess, better try and see for yourself.

Answer (score 3):

You can utilize a ROW_NUMBER to get the max (or min) salary:

```
SELECT *
FROM Usertable u
LEFT JOIN
 (
   select Userid, Salary,
      row_number() 
      over (partition by Userid
            order by Salary desc) as rn
   from Salarytable
 ) as s 
ON u.Userid = s.userid
AND rn = 1
```

And in Teradata you could apply the `rn = 1`filter using QUALIFY within the Derived Table:

```
SELECT *
FROM Usertable u
LEFT JOIN
 (
   select Userid, Salary,
      row_number() 
      over (partition by Userid
            order by Salary desc) as rn
   from Salarytable
   qualify rn = 1
 ) as s 
ON u.Userid = s.userid
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 select distinct U.User, U.Name, S.Salary
 from UserTable U
 left join SalaryTable S on S.User = U.User
```